# Error message showing while pushing in Git

Tags: github

While i am pushing in Git I am finding the below error

! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/smitraDA/DataScienceProject2.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I have already Clone,Add -A, and Commit. As follows:

C:\Users\Dell-672206>git clone https://github.com/smitraDA/DataScienceProject2.git
fatal: destination path 'DataScienceProject2' already exists and is not an empty directory.

C:\Users\Dell-672206>cd DataScienceProject2

C:\Users\Dell-672206\DataScienceProject2>git add -A

C:\Users\Dell-672206\DataScienceProject2>git commit -m "version1"

I am finding the below error:

! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/smitraDA/DataScienceProject2.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Follow the hint do a `git pull`, then try pushing again afterwards.

Comment: `fatal: destination path 'DataScienceProject2' already exists and is not an empty directory.` - you need to **read** the outputs  of the commands you're running.

Comment: Thanks but,How can I add an additional file into an already existing Repository,which is in this case"dataScienceProject2"?The main issue lies here" This is usually caused by another repository pushing hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again",if you can please help to get this.

Answer (score -1):

In this situation, you have to fetch your data first from GitHub and pull all the changes from GitHub to your local repository AND then push to a remote repository. You can use the below commands:

```
$ git pull origin master
$ git push origin master
```